# How to Retrieve 3d Models from remote server and render in android

Tags: android, 3d, augmented-reality

Is there any way I can retrieve 3D model(test.obj) from remote server when event is triggered.
and rendered in android device. There can be two options 
a) Retrieve model and store in device and then render.
b) Retrieve model and render

I don't know how it will work, main thing is How do I retrieve a model, convert it into string, save on device and then reassemble? but in that case it wont work in case of .3ds models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can retrieve 3D models and corresponding material or texture image from remote server the same way as we download image from remote server using asyncTask and store it in External storage.

In PostExecute() of asyncTask we can render the 3d model dynamically using Rajawali like this ,

ObjParser objParser =  new ObjParser(RajawaliRenderer renderer, String fileOnSDCard)
objParser.parse();
BaseObject3D 3dModel = objParser.getParsedObject();